# why is setTimeout ignored in this program?

Tags: javascript

```
let text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

for(let i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    setTimeout(console.log(text.charAt(i)), 2000);
}
```

I need this text to be printed one character at once with 2 seconds delay but it is not stoping.
why using setTimeout has no effect it just goes on without any delays.

Comment: Change it to `setTimeout(() => console.log(text.charAt(i)), 2000)`

Comment: Because you must pass a function to `setTimeout`. It's not a `sleep` call, it's a "schedule for later and continue immediately"

Comment: thank you very much for response but why does it needs to have this can you give me a explanation or any source @DominikMatis

Comment: Because `console.log(..)` just returns value `undefined`, `setTimeout` needs a function

Comment: `()` calls a function immediately; you're just passing the return value of that function call to `setTimeout`.